# Is it possible to dynamicaly create JayData Entity / Model / Context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jaydata

Is it possible to dynamically create a JayData Entity Model and Context? and then to use them?

I make an Ajax call and then do the following

```
function prepareEntityModel(json)
{
    // var entity = {
    //  Id: { type: "int", key:true },
    //  Name: { type: "string" },
    // });

    $data.Entity.extend("someData" + id, entity);
}
```

then I try to create a context.  To my suprise this seemed to work: `var t= "someData" + 81`

```
function createContext(t)
{
    $data.EntityContext.extend(t + "Context", {
        t: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: t },
    });

    var fn = eval(t + "Context");

    var context = new fn({
        name: "webSql",
        databaseName: "aDB"
    });

    return context;
}
```

the context even seems to respond to `onReady()` event.  But the table is created with the name "t".  At this point I have essentailly resorted to guessing.  Inside the Context I have no access to my data via the usal route of `context["someData" + id).addMany(data);`

I have been using JayData for less than 24hours so I apologies If this is nonsensical with the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a type, you get back the type definition, like

```
 var mytype = $data.Entity.extend("someData" + id, entity);
 var newInstance = new mytype();
```

when you declare the context, you also get back the context definition, no need to eval()

```
var contexttype = $data.EntityContext.extend(t + "Context", {...
var context = new contexttype({...
```

the table name can be specified with 'tableName' parameter (easier) or by giving the entityset a good name (harder), something like:

```
var contextDef = {};
contextDef[t] = { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: t };
var fn = $data.EntityContext.extend(t + "Context", contextDef);
```

Hope this helps, please do not hesitate to ask more questions here or in our forum. When you have a problem the best way is to create a small jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hey, I liked the "You are the man!" bit! I'm just working through your suggestions (finally escaped for lunch).

Comment: You are the man! I just removed to give a more professional answer :)

Comment: Can you tell us what are you up to with dynamic model?

Comment: We allow the user to define their data, and therefore it's structure so the the storage mechanism/structure on the device has to be flexible.